# How to Stream Video over UDP from GStreamer 1.0 to VLC

Tags: udp, video-streaming, gstreamer, vlc, gstreamer-1.0

I am planning to use GStreamer as the new video-streaming library for my application, but I am trying to test the basic capabilities first. Unfortunately there is a documentation problem, particularly re: Windows and v1.x

I can play a local video file in GStreamer. I can play a video in GStreamer that is being streamed over UDP or RTP by VLC. I can stream the videotestsrc from GStreamer to VLC.

### I cannot stream a local saved video from GStreamer to VLC. How do I do that?

Video format .mp4

VLC version 3.0.4

Gstreamer version 1.16

---

### (Some of the ) Tested commands

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=C:/Users/me/Desktop/big_buck_bunny.mp4 ! queue ! udpsink port=1234
```

```
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.027096112
```

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=C:/Users/me/Desktop/big_buck_bunny.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=1234
```

```
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
Execution ended after 0:00:00.027096112
```

No explicit errors from the previous commands but VLC received nothing and Wireshark saw nothing

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=C:/Users/me/Desktop/big_buck_bunny.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=1234
```

Many lines, lots of conflicting information about cap formats.

[Pastebin output](https://pastebin.com/2G3fdxWG).

I've tried a lot of caps combinations but nothing has worked so far. One that I tried:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=C:/Users/1137824/Desktop/big_buck_bunny.mp4 ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=600 ! avenc_mpeg4 ! rtpmp4vpay config-interval=3 ! udpsink port=1234
```

```
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

---

Trying streaming from VLC to Gstreamer to VLC (thought maybe GStreamer was sending the entire video in one packet instead of frame-by-frame)

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=1234 ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=1212`

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0: GStreamer error: negotiation problem.
Additional debug info:
../gst-libs/gst/rtp/gstrtpbasepayload.c(714): gst_rtp_base_payload_chain (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH264Pay:rtph264pay0:
No input format was negotiated, i.e. no caps event was received. Perhaps you need a parser or typefind element before the payloader
```

`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=1234 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink port=1212`

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

Answer (score 2):

To be able to receive from VLC you need to transmit your config from your `rtph264pay` element. This is done with `config-interval` value of the element. For example:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=C:/Users/me/Desktop/big_buck_bunny.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink port=1234
```

For the receiving side. VLC needs a `.sdp` file for the description of network stream. You can create a simple text file with a text editor, and write the contents into the file. An Example sdp file will be like follows:

```
v=0
m=video 1234 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

Here you, describe to VLC that you will receive a `H264` video stream from port `1234`, and it is in `RTP` packets with payload of`96`. You tell it to listen from `IP4` == `127.0.0.1`.

Feel free to modify this to your needs.

Comment: It works when using gdiscreencapsrc as the src but not with the file. I've tried starting the receiver (VLC) first and starting the streamer(Gstreamer) first. Also tried with a .mpeg and a .wmv file.
I installed GraphViz. Is there any information there that could help me?

Comment: Could you run the pipeline that's not working, with `-v` and share the output here?

Comment: [gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location= C:/Users/me/Desktop/big_buck_bunny.mp4 ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! "video/x-h264,profile=baseline" ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=-1 ! udpsink host=138.126.18.79 port=1234](https://pastebin.com/zzSqEdy3)